# jQuery select link not working on Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, asp.net-core

I want to have an option in `select` that takes a user to other page after clicking it.
Below function works on Edge and Mozilla, on Chrome not:

```
<select>
    <option value="@Url.Action("Home")" id="some-id"> Take me somewhere
    </option>
</select>

<script>
    $('#some-id').click(function () {
        window.location.href = this.value; 
    });
</script>
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must take a value from `select` Element. That way you can check if select value has changed and take user selected value.

```
<select id='some-id'>
    <option value="@Url.Action("Home")" > Take me somewhere
    </option>
</select>

<script>
    $('#some-id').on('change', function (event) {
        window.location = event.target.value; 
    });
</script>
```

P.s.: Better not to use `this` keyword but take it from event target. As using `this` can get You in trouble.

Answer (score 1):

I'd rewrite your code:

```
<select id='some-id'>
    <option value="@Url.Action("Home")" > Take me somewhere
    </option>
</select>

<script>
    $('#some-id').on('change', function () {
        window.location.href = this.value; 
    });
</script>
```